# Selecting customers with multiple purchases

Tags: sql, postgresql

[teble relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zTqL.png)
I have 4 tables for keeping track of purchases by clients. My goal is to select the names of clients that purchased 2 specific products (e.g. book and pencils)

The query which I thought of (and which is obviously incorrect) is:

```
    FROM customer c
join purchase p on c.customer_id = p.customer_id
join product pr on p.product_id = pr.product_id
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Purchase
    WHERE p.customer_id = c.customer_id
        AND pr.product_name = 'Book')
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Purchase
    WHERE p.customer_id = c.customer_id
        AND pr.product_name = 'Pencils')
```

Which return nothing, when I know that there is at least 1 customer than fits the criteria.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in`, `group by`, and `having` to fetch all `customer_id` which bought both `pencil` **and** `book`. The `having` is there to ensure both items actually bought.

```
 with
     relevant_purchases as
         (
           select customer_id
           from purchase pu
           left join product pr
           on pu.product_id = pr.product_id
           where product_name in ('book', 'pencil')
           group by customer_id
           having count(distinct pu.product_id) = 2
         )
 select *
 from customer c
 where exists (
       select *
       from relevant_purchases rp
       where c.customer_id = rp.customer_id
     );
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vdpUWSse7gcLi1CmnNrRgs/1

Comment: Thank you ! Although I have a following question, if I was to add another condition such as specific month of purchase, e.g. may of 2020 , would it go into relevant_purchase too? I added `where name in ('Teddy bear', 'LEGO') and pu.date_sold BETWEEN  ’01.05.2020’ AND ’31.05.2020’` ; and it broke again

Comment: @HPOS i want to say yes, but i'm not sure why yours broke given mine [works just fine](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vdpUWSse7gcLi1CmnNrRgs/2).. maybe we miss something?

Comment: Yeah, it was on me. Didn't check the date format. Thank you again !

Comment: @HPOS glad be of help. i have stared at your comment for a while and still didn't notice the date, lol.